# Multiple VueJS apps on a page sharing common VueJS module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, external

I have a page which is loading 3 different VueJS app. When these apps are compiled all 3 of them include VueJS framework code in their respective bundle. I am bundling using Webpack.

I know, App1 will always load before App2 & App3. How can configure webpack for App2 & App3 to use VueJS code loaded by App1 bundle?

I tried webpack's "external" property as directed in this [article](https://itnext.io/sharing-global-vue-instance-between-multiple-webpack-projects-abfb0aa9d3e), but I don't want to expose Vue in global scope.

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-reusing-module-in-multiple-entries-c9b3dae0ebbc  https://github.com/fingerpan/vue-cli-plugin-dll

Comment: @Saf the IVO GELOV solution should work for you but if you want to do micro-frontends I recommend this framework which supports vuejs https://single-spa.js.org/